# EnqueueWork requiring Serialization causes AsyncTask to crash

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, serialization, android-asynctask

The idea behind this project is to have a Progress bar running while uploading a Database to a webService

I have an AsyncTask that does some work, then calls a service and awaits for it to finish before calling onPostExecute()

```
private class UploadDatabaseAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Long, Void> {

    private AlertDialog dialog;
    private Activity activity;
    private TextView messageView;
    private String location;
    private long maxSize;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    UploadDatabaseAsyncTask(Activity activity, long maxSize, String location) {
        super();
        this.location = location;
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressBar = new ProgressBar(activity);
        progressBar.setMax(100);
        progressBar.setProgress(0);

        dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setTitle("Uploading").setView(progressBar).create();
        messageView = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);

       // dialog.show();

        if (activity != null && activity.getView() != null)
        {
            activity.getView().setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

            activity.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(App.getAppContext(), R.color.grey));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Long... values) {
        messageView.setText(values[0] + " / " + maxSize);

        BigDecimal current = new BigDecimal(values[0]);
        BigDecimal max = new BigDecimal(maxSize);

        BigDecimal progress = current.divide(max, 3, RoundingMode.UP);

        progressBar.setProgress(Integer.valueOf(progress.multiply(new BigDecimal(100)).toString()));
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();

        final Object lock = new Object();

        final boolean[] active = new boolean[]{true};

        DatabaseSyncService.SyncProgressCallback callback = new DatabaseSyncService.SyncProgressCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(long progress) {
                onProgressUpdate(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                active[0] = false;
                lock.notify();
            }
        };


        intent.putExtra(DATABASE_ID, callback);
        intent.putExtra("LOCATION", location);
        DatabaseSyncService.enqueueWork(activity, intent);

        synchronized (lock)
        {
            while (active[0])
            {
                try {
                    lock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Void aVoid) {
        if (activity != null && activity.getView() != null)
        {
            activity.getView().setOnTouchListener(null);
            activity.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(App.getAppContext(), R.color.transparent));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        if (activity != null && activity.getView() != null)
        {
            activity.getView().setOnTouchListener(null);
            activity.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(App.getAppContext(), R.color.transparent));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) { 
        if (activity != null && activity.getView() != null) 
        {
            activity.getView().setOnTouchListener(null);
            activity.getView().setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(App.getAppContext(), R.color.transparent))
        }

       AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(App.getAppContext());
       builder.setTitle("Upload Complete");
       builder.setMessage("You upload was completed!");
       builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { }
       });

       builder.show();
    }
}
```

I'm running into an issue with the DatabaseSyncService.enqueueWork() method trying to serialize the AsyncTask, which won't work. Any idea why it is trying to do this?

StackTrace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
Process: com.app.app, PID: 15935
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.app.app.api.SettingApi$UploadDatabaseAsyncTask$2)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1786)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1734)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:801)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1506)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1181)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:841)
    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:10199)
    at android.app.job.JobWorkItem.writeToParcel(JobWorkItem.java:117)
    at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.enqueue(IJobScheduler.java:205)
    at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.enqueue(JobSchedulerImpl.java:53)
    at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$JobWorkEnqueuer.enqueueWork(JobIntentService.java:343)
    at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService.enqueueWork(JobIntentService.java:523)
    at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService.enqueueWork(JobIntentService.java:501)
    at com.ascsoftware.ascora.sync.DatabaseSyncService.enqueueWork(DatabaseSyncService.java:37)
    at com.ascsoftware.ascora.api.SettingApi$UploadDatabaseAsyncTask.doInBackground(SettingApi.java:291)
    at com.ascsoftware.ascora.api.SettingApi$UploadDatabaseAsyncTask.doInBackground(SettingApi.java:212)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
 Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.app.app.api.SettingApi$UploadDatabaseAsyncTask
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1233)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1597)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1558)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1481)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1227)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1781)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1734) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:801) 
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1506) 
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1181) 
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:841) 
    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:10199) 
    at android.app.job.JobWorkItem.writeToParcel(JobWorkItem.java:117) 
    at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.enqueue(IJobScheduler.java:205) 
    at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.enqueue(JobSchedulerImpl.java:53) 
    at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$JobWorkEnqueuer.enqueueWork(JobIntentService.java:343) 
    at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService.enqueueWork(JobIntentService.java:523) 
    at androidx.core.app.JobIntentService.enqueueWork(JobIntentService.java:501) 
    at com.app.app.sync.DatabaseSyncService.enqueueWork(DatabaseSyncService.java:37) 
    at com.app.app.api.SettingApi$UploadDatabaseAsyncTask.doInBackground(SettingApi.java:291) 
    at com.app.app.api.SettingApi$UploadDatabaseAsyncTask.doInBackground(SettingApi.java:212) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
(HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

Here is the Callback

```
public interface SyncProgressCallback extends Serializable {
    void onProgress(long progress);
    void onFinish();
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you calling a Service?  If you really must, there is a well known trick that you can use with a bound service, that will work here: https://github.com/bmeike/ServiceExperiment/blob/d5632d1c861f5b3688e546a20bf6ca226d6eeac6/app0/src/main/java/net/callmeike/android/services/app0/PrefixActivity.java#L40

Comment: BTW.. instead of waiting on that lock, you might want to consider a `CountDownLatch`

Comment: Calling the methods from the "Upload Database" button in the app, which runs the Async Task that i want to use for the onProgressUpdate because i'm lazy haha, then  in doInBackground i start the DatabaseSyncService JobIntentService to perform all the WebService calls as i still want this to be running in the background and make sure it gets completed, i pass in the callback so i can still update the ProgressBar from the Async if they keep the app alive, then will call onFinish which will end the doInBackground method and force the user to acknowledge the completion before continuing

Comment: I might look into the CountDownLatch! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line does not work:

```
intent.putExtra(DATABASE_ID, callback);
```

To put an object into an `Intent`, the object must implement `Serializable`/`Parcelable` interface. Moreover, the same requirement applies to all the fields of the object.

Though your `callback` object (which belongs to type `DatabaseSyncService.SyncProgressCallback`) implements `Serializable`, but it is instanced from an inner class `callback = new DatabaseSyncService.SyncProgressCallback() {...}`. According to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#a4539), `java.io.NotSerializableException` occurs in your case because:

> - serializing such an inner class instance will result in serialization of its associated outer class instance as well
> - Serialization of inner classes (i.e., nested classes that are not static member classes), including local and anonymous classes, is strongly discouraged

This means that you have to make your outer class `UploadDatabaseAsyncTask` implements `Serializable` which in turns must applies to all of its fields, and so on.

That's quite frustrating.

As a rule of thumb, please consider put something lightweight / pure data, not complex objects with complex dependencies, to an `Intent`.

Back to your code, one easy fix could be passing the `callback` object to the `DatabaseSyncService.enqueueWork` method:

```
    //intent.putExtra(DATABASE_ID, callback);
    intent.putExtra("LOCATION", location);
    DatabaseSyncService.enqueueWork(activity, intent, callback);
```

Inside `enqueueWork()` use `callback` directly instead of *deserializing* from the intent.

Comment: DatabaseSyncService.SyncProgressCallback is Serializable 

    
    public interface SyncProgressCallback extends Serializable {
        void onProgress(long progress);
        void onFinish();
    }

Or does this not work?

Comment: I'll add the Callback into the question!

Comment: Okay I believe I understand now! I will quickly work that in and let you know! Thank you!

Comment: Yes! You were correct, the inner class was causing the issues, I did what you mentioned and passed it as a argument instead and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the inner class dilemma as well, something sneaky to look out for in the future